# Is there any video where I can see how different data rates impact daily activities?

Tags: computer-architecture

I've been learning about data speed and width and the rate of the bus where information is transmitted between components. But I can't see or understand how fast is the transmission.

For example, in theory, I've read about how PCI operates at 133MBps and 266mbps and such, however, I can't seem to comprehend how fast the data transmission really is. Does 133MBps mean that the speed of transferring the instructions of the peripherals to the CPU is more lagging than the transfer of 266MBps?

If my way of thinking is wrong, please help me understand.

Comment: instructions of the peripherals(assuming you are talking about drivers) are stored in the secondary memory and loaded into the main memory by the OS, so the cpu accesses them by a memory bus(broadly speaking). The PCI is used to add components like video,sound or network cards(basically anything which the cpu doesn't access directly).

Comment: as someone who wrote some games I think an interesting way to comprehend it is megabytes per frame. If you want your game to work at 60 frames per second, then 133MBps means you can send about 2 megabytes of data to the graphics card per frame, otherwise the game won't run as fast as you want.